# Is there a way to count all words on a sheet while making specific exceptions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I am currently trying to display the number of words of all the words on a specific sheet in a single cell.

I am currently using a formula that looks like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(Armies!B3:D&CHAR(32)) , ">>>" , "") , "Description WIP" , "") , "%N/C%" , "") , "\n" , ""))
```

As you can see, this formula takes all the words of a specific range on the sheet "Armies" and puts them in one single cell while "ignoring" strings like ">>>","Description WIP" etc. (I then just simply count the words in that cell in a separate formula). The problem with this is that one single Google Sheet cell can only contain 5000 characters. Is there any way to do this in one step?

Comment: Is this an Excel question or google sheets?

Comment: Sorry this is a google sheets question. Edited the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(query(Sheet1!A1:A,,2^99) , ">>>" , "") , "Description WIP" , "") , "%N/C%" , "") , "\n" , ""))`

the key is to replace `CONCATENATE` with `query`.

The trick is the query:

- the formula takes the third argument: number of rows of header
- this third argument has to be a big number: 2^99 is big enough
- then the number of header rows is > 1, the query formula joins the header automatically
- the second argument of the formula is query string, it may be empty, which gives the default "select all" → `select *`

---

my sample is tested with 1 column `A1:A` for more columns double the query:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(query(transpose(query(Sheet1!A1:B,,2^99)),,2^99) , ">>>" , "") , "Description WIP" , "") , "%N/C%" , "") , "\n" , ""))`

this sample works for 2 columns `A1:B` because it uses the second query:
`query(transpose(query(Sheet1!A1:B,,2^99)),,2^99)`

the inner query gives multiple columns, the outer query+transpose converts the result to the single cell.